# Tab index handling - ASP.NET MVC form controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web page that has basic registration field like Name, DOB, Address etc. The page has some controls (text box, DOB etc) that will be shown or hidden based on a radio button selection. Currently, when the end user fills up the page using tab key the hidden controls are getting focus and tab out is not working as expected (Current implementation does not have tab indexes set).

I tried manually setting the tab indexes in a incremental order for all the controls. But moving back and forth or after switching between those radio button selections, tab out scenario is not working properly.

Is there any work around to handle this scenario? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What style do you use for hiding the controls? `display: none`, `opacity: 0` or else?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan opacity:0

Comment: You need to set `display: none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0` so controls are removed completely from the flow. `opacity: 0` means that the controls are still there, just invisible, they can still receive focus and input, on the code snippet below, you can still click in the *invisible* control between the two visible controls.

`display: none` means the controls are not there anymore so they can't receive focus and input.

You can refer to code snippet below to see the comparison.

```css
.opacity .hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  }

.display .hidden {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<h3>Opacity: 0 style</h3>
<form class="opacity">
  <input type="text" />  
  <input type="text" class="hidden" />  
  <input type="text" />  
</form>
<h3>Display: none style</h3>
<form class="display">
  <input type="text" />  
  <input type="text" class="hidden" />  
  <input type="text" />  
</form>
```